# How do you run JMH Benchmarks on Scala Code in a Gradle Project using the Gradle Scala Plugin

Tags: scala, gradle, gradle-plugin, jmh

I am looking for a way to run JMH benchmarks on Scala code in gradle projects. For SBT there is a [plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh). How can you do the same if your are using Gradle perhaps using another plugin or writing a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [JMH Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin). The default configuration should allow to write JMH benchmarks in Java that test Scala code.

If you want to write the benchmarks themselves in Scala you would have to add the plugin and dependency manually like this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

sourceSets {
    jmh {
        scala.srcDir 'src/jmh/scala'
    }
}

jmh {
    include = ['.*']
    jmhVersion = '1.15'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.1'
}
```

And then add the benchmark code in `src/jmh/scala`.